# Why is my process (Google Chrome) running in a Docker container being killed?

Tags: docker, google-chrome

I want to run Google Chrome within a Docker container.

I have followed https://medium.com/dot-debug/running-chrome-in-a-docker-container-a55e7f4da4a8, which, while out-of-date, works with a few mods and installs the necessary prerequisites.

Chrome runs, but when I try to do anything too hard (say load Google Maps), it either crashes all of Chrome or just one tab (with a SIGKILL).

MY feeling is that this is a resource constraint, but I am rather confused.  The other processes within the container (desktop manager for example) keep running, it is just Chrome that is being killed.

I am happy to publish the Docker build file, docker image or docker-compose file if that helps.

Thanks in advance.

I have added

```
deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 10g
```

To the docker-compose.yml file, but that made no difference.  The machine it is running on is using only 10% of its memory (64GB) at idle, so this is not an issue.